# Login Issue with Weblogic in Docker

Tags: docker, weblogic, weblogic12c

I created a Weblogic generic container for version 12.1.3 based on the official Docker images from Oracle at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles
Command:    buildDockerImage.sh -g -s -v 12.1.3
This creates the image oracle/weblogic:12.1.3-generic

Using a modified version of sample dockerfile for 1213-domain, I built the Weblogic container. 
Note: changed the base image to be generic, instead of developer
docker build -t 1213-domain --build-arg ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin123" -f myDockerfile .

Pushed the built image to Amazon ECR and ran the container using the AWS ECS. Configured the port mappings as 0:7001, set memory soft limit as 1024, nothing else changed in default ECS settings. I have an application load balancer in the front, which receives traffic at 443 port and forwards to the containers. In the browser I get a login page for Weblogic, when I enter username as weblogic and password as admin123, I get the error:

Authentication Denied

[image]

Interestingly when I go to the container and connect to the weblogic using WLST, it works fine.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-99-103-141 ~]$ docker exec -it 458 bash
[oracle@4580238db23f mydomain]$ /u01/oracle/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Jython scans all the jar files it can find at first startup. Depending on the system, this process may take a few minutes to complete, and WLST may not return a prompt right away.

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline> connect("weblogic","admin123","t3://localhost:7001")
Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server "AdminServer" that belongs to domain "mydomain".

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
Admin port should be used instead.

wls:/mydomain/serverConfig>
```

Any hints on what can be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting indeed. :) .. You are sure there is no special characters or so when you entering the username and password. Try typing the same if you are coping.
Also as backup, since you are able to login to WLST you can try two option.

1. Resetting the current password of weblogic or try adding new username and password.
   below link will help
   http://middlewarebuzz.blogspot.com/2013/06/weblogic-password-reset.html

or

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4962

Comment: doesn't seem to be a password issue. It looks more like a HTTPS issue, wherein the Amazon ELB is blocking requests to the container. Password is "admin123", so no special characters at all. I have decrypted the password in the container, it is the same which I have set, so changing password doesn't seem to help unfortunately. Nevertheless thank you for the suggestion.